# Using a variable as a button type with MessageBoxButtons

Tags: c#, wpf

I know that I can do this:

```
var randomBtn = MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel;
MessageBox.Show("text","title",randomBtn);
```

However, how can I do something like this (the example is obviously not working)?

```
var randomBtn = "YesNoCancel";
MessageBox.Show("text","title",MessageBoxButtons.randomBtn);
```

`randomBtn` is the result of previous checkups, and depending on the outcome can be either `YesNoCancel`, `AbortRetryIgnore`, `OKCancel`, or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageBoxButtons` is an enum. Thus, you should be able to achieve this by using `Enum.parse`

```cs
var randomBtnName = "YesNoCancel";
// Get the enum entry matching the button
MessageBoxButtons randomBtn = (MessageBoxButtons) Enum.Parse(typeof(MessageBoxButtons), randomBtnName);
MessageBox.Show("text", "title", randomBtn);
```

Comment: With this, I get an error - `cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons'`. I get the general idea though - use the string as something which refers to a specific enumerated object.

Comment: Oups : ```Parse``` returns an ```Object```. I updated with an explcit cast

Comment: Right, kept at it, and came to the same conclusion - had to cast it. Thank you!